# How to download a file from sftp using script task in SSIS?

Tags: .net, ssis

Tried using the sharpSSH dll(VB.net),but couldn't find the solution.

[image: Find the below error]
[image: My script]

Comment: Did you add the assembly to the GAC?  Try that and then close and reopen Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't have gacutil.exe in my machine.I have BIDS alone the above script i tried in SSIS using script task.

Comment: Check out the way [WinSCP recommends using PowerShell](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#on_production_or_user_s_machine)

Comment: Run Windows Explorer as admin and drag the assembly to c:\windows\assembly if you don't have gacutil.exe

Comment: @Ako I tried but not working

Comment: @sorrell can you give some sample for WinSCP

Comment: @dinesh I provided a link in my previous comment.

Comment: So did the assembly go into GAC? And is the error the same?

Comment: @Ako I tried with Tamir.SharpSSH.dll it is not working for me.

Comment: @sorrell Thanks a lot . Now its working fine using with WinSCP.